# Atom feed in the chatroom is not working

Tags: bug, chat, feed, atom

We have got an Atom feed set up in our chatroom, and it is never posting any messages into the chatroom.

The Atom feed url is: https://github.com/skiwi2/JavaLuaInteropTest/commits/master.atom

We did see that, when adding the feed, it got the five latest entries and parsed them, but after that it never did anything anymore.

Could anyone look into this?